# Is there any python lambda function that stops the pipeline execution if vulnerabilities found in Docker Image Scanning?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pipeline, amazon-cloudwatch

I've created a code pipeline that pushes Docker images to the ECR Repository. Before pushing image scan on push is enabled which scans for vulnerabilities in the Docker-Image.
I need to ensure that Docker images that my code pipeline does not deploy any artifacts if ECR Code Scanning reports any vulnerabilities so that we prevent deploy of application with vulnerabilities.
I need to develop a python lambda script that gets the vulnerability notification from CloudWatch as lambda is the target from sns notification.

Comment: This should be tested in the `test` stage. Assuming you use CodeBuild? So CodeBuild should scan the image or Dockerfile for any issues.

Comment: here ECR is scanning for issues. My requirement is to stop the pipeline if issues found to stop publishing to artificats. I've added manual approval task. But I need to automate it using lambda.

Comment: So you have scan on push? Isn't this process asynchronous? Meaning that when you push, scan findings will be known later on? By this time your pipeline may have already finished finishes, or has to stop and wait for the scan results?

Comment: Yes Scan On Push enabled and it is asynchronous which finds the scan findings later on. My intention here is stop publishing the image into the artifact which has vulnerabilities by adding an approval action which is taken care by lambda written in python or any other language.

Comment: Yes it should be possible. You could possibly have an approval action to be SNS. The SNS would invoke lambda, and lambda using boto3 calls `stop_pipeline_execution`  or `put_approval_result`.

Comment: Manual approval task is done. But approval action cannot be SNS. There is no action as such to have SNS as action approver. Therefore I'm automating the approval task using python lambda. Unfortunately I'm stuck in connectors between sns and lambda.